# PHP with MySQLi fetch does not return rows with NULL on LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table `matches` with rows containing reference IDs for sports, regions, countries and leagues among other things. I use `LEFT JOIN` to find the actual league name because not all matches have a league ID.

I use the following:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT leagues.name, matches.league
    FROM matches
        LEFT JOIN leagues  
            ON leagues.short = matches.league 
    WHERE leagues.lang = ? AND matches.sport = ? AND matches.region = ? AND matches.country = ? 
    ORDER BY leagues.name ASC");

$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$lang,$sport_short,$region_short,$country_short);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($league,$league_short);
```

If I at this point use `var_dump($league)` or `var_dump($league_short)` I see the `NULL` values. However after I try to fetch the rows with `while ($stmt->fetch) {...}` no rows with `NULL` gets included, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query `leagues.lang` will also be `NULL` if no match is found and then it will be filtered out by the `WHERE` clause.

So you can either drop the `leagues.lang = ?` in the `WHERE` clause or you can modify it to something like this:

```
((leagues.short IS NOT NULL AND leagues.lang = ?) OR leagues.short is NULL)
```